# How can I condition a double variable to be less than 500 while creating the table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

So my teacher asked me to condition the double variable so it can't be higher than 500. How can I do that when creating the table?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing as you refer to both a variable and a table. My guess is that your teacher wants you to read up on [CHECK CONSTRAINTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn how to use the CHECK CONSTRAINT IN SQL.
W3School is always the first place you can learn it by yourself: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp